# How to copy WordPress theme menu style to a menu created automatically by a plugin?

Tags: css, wordpress, plugins

I am using a client portal plugin that automatically creates menus on client pages. The color and font styling I was able to match via CSS, but the menu has a little animation that I would like to also duplicate so the menus are consistent on every page. I assume - hope - I can copy this effect from the theme and insert it into the file governing the plugin's menu styles. I need to know, first, where to locate the menu style in a theme, and then, where to place it in the plugin. All suggestions are welcome and appreciated. Below are some suspects, but in all honesty, I'm just guessing here:

From the header php file:

```
<header id="masthead" class="site-header <?php echo astrid_has_header(); ?>" role="banner">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="site-branding col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                <?php astrid_branding(); ?>
            </div>
            <div class="btn-menu col-md-8 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"><i class="fa fa-navicon"></i></div>
            <nav id="mainnav" class="main-navigation col-md-8 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" role="navigation">
                <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary', 'menu_id' => 'primary-menu' ) ); ?>
            </nav><!-- #site-navigation -->
        </div>
    </header><!-- #masthead -->
```

From an Inspection of the plugin menu:

```
<ul id="primary-menu" class="menu"><li id="menu-item-2232" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-2232"><a href="https://lukeobritt-new.staging.wpmudev.host/welcome-to-the-client-portal/">NOT A CLIENT?</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Without getting your hands dirty on an actual site, it's hard to advise specifically.   Sometimes, just using something like Chrome DevTools and a code editor, you can hack your way to an easy solution - if you correctly guess the critical selectors being used by the original CSS or CSS + JS/jQuery. Better, but requiring more work and knowledge ,and possibly an expanded toolset, will be to determine how exactly the effect is produced, and then emulating from scratch.

Comment: Thanks for the response CK. Yes, I am making progress and learning quite a bit about theme and plugin editing, enqueuing stylesheets and why developers are so well paid. If someone had responded with an easy copy and paste fix, none of this learning would be taking place.

Answer (score 0):

I'd guess there is a javascript file used in the plugin (in addition to the css you found) that completes the menu animation. With some detective work you might be able to find the javascript library or code and turn around to use it with the new menu you're creating.

Dig into the source files of the plugin or inspect the source of the page and see what js files are loaded to identify which might be tied with that plugin.

After you find some js files to inspect or test. Link to the possible js files/libraries on your new page testing out the menu and see what happens.